# Windows TS licensing not allowing more than 2 connections

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2, licensing, remoteapp

I have two servers both running Windows Server 2012 R2. One has the Remote Desktop License Role and the other has the rest of the RD roles (Session Host, Broker, Web Access). I have the license server configured on the RD server and it shows my 10  licenses and is configured as Per User.

My problem is that I can only connect two users to Remote Apps. If a 3rd person tries to connect it just hangs at "Negotiating Credentials". This also happens on both Windows and Mac.

I have set the local computer policy **Limit number of connections** to 100.

Am I missing a step somewhere? How do I get it to use my licenses?

Comment: Have you confirmed the RDSH server sees and is able to communicate with the licensing server?

Comment: Yes, in the licensing diagnoser it shows the licensing server and the licenses available.( it says 8 of 10 available)

Comment: Can you establish more than 2 traditional remote desktop sessions to the server?

Comment: No i can not, hangs at Negotiating Credentials

Comment: In RDSH Configuration, edit your RDP-Tcp Connection properties and on the *Network Adapter* tab, is it set to **Unlimited connections**?

Comment: I do not have an option to edit Tcp Connections or do i have the Network Adapter Tab under the RDSH Config.

Comment: I gave you instructions for the wrong version of Windows.  Try this.  Use Group Policy to set the item **Limit number of connections** to Unlimited (or a large #). It's found at `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Connections`.

Comment: I already set it to 100 before i got on here for help.

Comment: OK. That, being something you've already tried, should be noted in your original question.  Is anything logged in the event log on the server when trying to establish the 3rd unsuccessful connection?

Comment: "Listener RDP-Tcp received a connection" is all it shows. No errors

Comment: Unfortunately, enterprise hardware or software questions are off-topic here—please try [sf] instead. See the [help/on-topic] for details. (Please don't cross-post—if you post your question there, you should delete the question here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you configure the deployment in Per-User mode, You shouldn't see any connection failures due to lack of licenses.

From what you said, 2 out of 10 CAL's were issued to two users who connected successfully which means licensing server and licensing configuration on RDSH  is working fine.

The problem seems to be on RDSH, can you try after removing any local policies just to make sure it is not the issue.

If that doesn't work, I would start over building my RDSH.

Comment: I rebuilt the RDSH machine and everything seems to be working. I have 4 connections to the remoteapps as i type this.